# REST API - POST Behavior

Tags: rest, http-post, api-design

In a true REST API how is POST supposed to behave for an operation like this

Supposse there is a
POST v1/report --> some body with id1, id2  - passed in a request

id1, id2 are part of unique index. For their combination needs to be unique for every resource.
If there already exists data in the table with id1 and id2 is POST supposed to

1. return that data. In this case do what GET would do
2. return an exception since there already exists data.

Since POST is not idempotent what is it supposed to do in true sense.

Making sure I implement REST API verbs in the correct way.

Comment: https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.